# Removing spaces in a downloaded Text File in VB

Tags: vb.net, newline, trim

I am coding a downloader and basically how it works is I put a few links in a text file which looks like this:

```
1   http://127.0.0.1:8080/patch/patches/test1.rar
2   http://127.0.0.1:8080/patch/patches/test2.rar
3   http://127.0.0.1:8080/patch/patches/test3.rar
```

So I download this text file via a web client in vb.net with this following code:

```
    Dim PatchList = wc.DownloadString("http://127.0.0.1:8080/patch/PatchList.txt").Trim
    Dim tLines As String() = PatchList.Split(Environment.NewLine)

    For Each NewLine As String In tLines
        Dim tVersionAndUrl As String() = NewLine.Split(vbTab)
        Dim encText As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
        Dim btText() As Byte
        btText = encText.GetBytes(tVersionAndUrl(0))

        If tVersionAndUrl.Length < 2 Then
            Exit For
        End If

        If Integer.Parse(tVersionAndUrl(0)) < Integer.Parse(CVersion.Text) Then
            Dim TempPath As String = "\launcher\temp.rar"
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(tVersionAndUrl(1), Me.GetFileName(tVersionAndUrl(1)))
            CVersion.Text = tVersionAndUrl(0)
        End If

    Next
    MsgBox("Client is up to date")
```

Everything works great but the only problem is that when it downloads the file it puts a some sort of space before each number, I believe this space may just be a normal space or it could be due to the new line, I wasn't able to trim it because when I did nothing happened. So it looks like this:

http://puu.sh/45B9j.png

But the first line is fine and it has no space.

I have tried lots of different strategies to remove it but I was unsuccessful.

EDIT: So okay I tried to make sure if it was a new line or a space but it appears to be neither?

I used this code:

```
    If tLines.Contains(Environment.NewLine) Then
        MsgBox("It's a freaking new line!")
    ElseIf tLines.Contains(" ") Then
        MsgBox("It's a freaking space!")
    Else
        MsgBox("There's no new lines or spaces. Huh?")
    End If
```

and I got the last message box confirming it was neither. Now I am confused.

EDIT2: As requested here is what I tried to remove the spaces/newlines.

```
Dim newString As String = tLines.ToString.Remove(Environment.NewLine)
```

Also tried:

```
Dim newString As String = tLines.ToString.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")
```

And I tried:

```
Dim NoSpace = Replace(tLines.ToString, Chr(13), vbNullString)
```

And This:

```
Dim TrimmedLines As String = tLines.ToString.Trim
```

Comment: Post your attempts at removing the space and the resulting output or error that proves it is not working.

Comment: @KarlAnderson I edited my main post.

Comment: Try to figure out what exactly are those spaces, maybe they are control characters like \0x0 or a \t (tab). Then replace properly.
Can you publish a sample file so we can figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try removing all characters from each string that don't fall within range of ascii characters (hex 0x20-0x7E) using a regular expression:

```
Dim PatchList = wc.DownloadString("http://127.0.0.1:8080/patch/PatchList.txt").Trim
Dim tLines As String() = PatchList.Split(Environment.NewLine)

For i As Integer = 0 To tLines.Length - 1

  tLines(i) = Regex.Replace(tLines(i), "[^\u0020-\u007E]", String.Empty)

Next
```

ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Oh this works partially. It does remove the space but it also removes the tab, is it possible to prevent it from removing the tab?

Comment: Repeat the above Regex with the range before and after the tab?

Comment: Solved it. I used \s? to remove all white spaces and then instead of splitting at tab I just split at "#".